# Object initializer with arguments of a generic type

Tags: c#, generics

How to initialize a new object of T with Id argument passed in?

```
private ICollection<T> AddRelationalData<T>(List<int> relationalDataIds)
        where T : class, new()
    {
        var relationalDataCollection = new Collection<T>()
        if (relationalDataIds != null && relationalDataIds.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var entry in relationalDataIds.Select(id => new T {Id = id}))
            {
                relationalDataCollection.Add(entry);
            }
        }
        return relationalDataCollection;
    }
```

Comment: you cant. you need to know a certain type here. only other way would be reflection but you don't know if T will have that property

Comment: You should use and interface here.

Comment: Every type which is used to call this method has an Id property, so it wouldn't be a problem. I hoped that there was a way to avoid reflection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a base class, which contains required properties:

```
public class Test
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
}

private ICollection<T> AddRelationalData<T>(List<int> relationalDataIds)
    where T : Test, new()
{
    var relationalDataCollection = new Collection<T>()
    if (relationalDataIds != null && relationalDataIds.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var entry in relationalDataIds.Select(id => new T {Id = id}))
        {
            relationalDataCollection.Add(entry);
        }
    }
    return relationalDataCollection;
}
```

Comment: exactly, and this is what I was referring to/hinting :)